Kiddish in the place where one eats on Pesach for those that don't eat “gebrockts”
Halachipedia says

In order to have Kiddish in the place where one eats and that the
Kiddish is considered a proper Kiddish, one must eat at least a
kezayit of mezonot, bread, or a reviyit of wine.

On Pesach when many don't eat “gebrockts” (food based on matzo meal), mezonot food is not available. One could still drink a reviyit of wine.
In such a case if the one making kiddush drinks a reviyit of wine, does that quit the obligation of those hearing kiddush or must they drink too?
Is there any way that eating other foods could solve the problem?

If the mekadesh ate mezonos on a regular shabbat would you think that'd help the listeners? I'd be very surprised to hear that

related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/56338/759

Not eating grbrockts doesn't stop you from eating matzah. Make Kiddush and then eat matzah. What's the problem?

You can fulfill kiddush through hearing someone else, but your obligation of seudah is the food that you eat. So the person making kiddush would drink 2 cups of wine, and everyone else would drink one. Alternatively (for what everyone is eating for their "seudah"), there is certainly a valid (if not universal) opinion in the Acharonim to eat olives, dates, grapes, figs, or pomegranates.

Aha @Shalom. Can you source the Acharonim about the fruits please?

You're question is just asking about if the same reviis one made for kiddish counts as the reviis of wine one most drink to count for the meal. All of the pesach stuff seems to be extra.

@AvrohomYitzchok Mishna Brurah and Chayei Adam are willing to rely on the Shiltei Giborim in a pinch. OC273, #26. See full answer below. There's no special rule about Pesach per se, but the question always comes up because people tend not to serve mezonos cake. (They are machmir on gebrochts, which is not in the Shulchan Aruch, and meikil on kiddush bemakom seudah, which is ... but nu ... c'est la vie ...)

Mishna Brurah, Orach Chayim 273, #26.

וע"כ מה שנוהגים לילך לבית חתן או מילה ואין שם כיסנין אחר קידוש רק
מיני מגדים אין לו לטעום שם כלל ולא סגי במה שהמקדש שותה כל הכוס אף שהוא
מחזיק רביעית דזה מהני רק לשותה עצמו אבל לא לאחרים
Therefore, when people go to a groom's house [for a post-wedding
celebration] or a circumcision, and there are no pastries after the
Kiddush, only sweets, one shouldn't eat anything at all. It is
insufficient that the person making Kiddush drinks the entire cup,
even if it holds a quarter-log, as that only works for the drinker
himself, not for others.


והנה בשלטי גבורים כתב דאף בפירות די דכל סעודת שבת נחשבת קבע אך דעת
הטור ושו"ע עיקר [מ"א] אך אם חלש לבו קצת ואין לו עתה מחמשת המינים לסעוד
אחר הכוס דעת איזה אחרונים דיש לסמוך על הש"ג בשחרית


However, the Shiltei Giborim wrote that even fruits suffice, as any Sabbath meal is considered "significant", though the opinion of Tur and Shulchan Aruch has primacy. But if one is feeling slightly fainthearted and has nothing made of the five grains [wheat, barley, spelt, oats, rye], on which to feast after the Kiddush cup, then it is the opinion of various Acharonim that one may rely on the Shiltei Giborim during the day [but not for the kiddush at night].

The Mishna Brurah's conclusion -- "good enough to rely on the Shiltei Giborim in a pinch" -- was also that of the Chayei Adam, over a century earlier. I don't know if that counted as one of the Mishna Brurah's aforementioned "Acharonim." But the heter is clearly on the books in cases of some need ... how that applies to a typical Pesach kiddush ... ask your rabbi.

B"H
You're question is about what counts as a meal after kiddush. All of the pesach related stuff seems extra.

if the one making kiddush drinks a reviyit of wine, does that quit the
obligation of those hearing kiddush or must they drink too?
Is there any way that eating other foods could solve the problem?

Source:

In order to have Kiddish in the place where one eats and that the
Kiddish is considered a proper Kiddish, one must eat at least a
kezayit of mezonot, bread, or a reviyit of wine.

Each person must eat a seuda in the place they heard kiddish: (Ibid):

If someone is reciting kiddush in one room and someone else is hearing
the kiddush in another room if the person listening to the kiddush is
going to eat his meal in the room where he is that is considered
kiddush in the place of the meal. The reason is that the one
fulfilling his obligation of kiddush needs to be in the room where he
is going to eat his meal and not where the person making kiddush
is.[89]

There's no indication in any commentators that I'm aware of that the listeners fulfill their obligation for the seuda by just the person making kiddush drinking another cup. It would be no different than the one making kiddush eating mezonos afterwards, in which case everyone listening must also eat mezonos/seuda for them to be yotzi kiddish.
In terms of other foods, there is at least one commentator that says one can use other foods that one makes the mein shalosh brocho on, although I'm not sure if it's kept in practice:
Source

The Bach agrees to this, saying that as long as what is eaten requires
one to make a bracha acharona (afterblessing) of "me-eyn shalosh"
(made on non-bread grain products, as well as on fruits from the seven
species of Israel and wine) a meal is considered to have occurred. The
Beit Yoseif agrees as well, adding in that the wine drunk must be a
different cup from that on which kiddush was made so that it is
noticeable that it is being used as a "meal." Rav Akiva Eiger notes
that wine may only be used according to the view that the expanded
bracha acharona of "me-eyn shalosh" is made on all of the seven
species of Israel, which includes grapes and thus wine. However,
according to the view that this blessing is only made on grain
products, the food eaten in this situation must be something made out
of one of the five grains (barley, rye, oats, wheat, spelt). The Magen
Avraham (O.C. 283:11) also allows any product of the five grains. The
Sha'arei Teshuva quotes the Shut Ginat Veradim, who frowns upon the
practice of making kiddush in the synagogue and then eating cake to
fulfill the requirement of a meal. However, he then cites the Birchei
Yoseif that such is the custom and there is nothing wrong with it.
Finally, the Mishna Berura (O.C. 283:25) claims that Rav Akiva Eiger's
personal view is that wine should not be used


"RAE notes that wine may only be used according to the view that... "me-eyn shalosh" is made on...wine. However, according to the view that this blessing is only made on grain products״ This must be a typo as everyone agrees wine gets a meeyn shalosh. RAE's suggestion is that wine only works according to those who hold the M3 on wine needs to be said where the wine was drunk which renders it kavua (giving us the bizarre logical process: Geonim [allegedly] only say wine works -> Magen Avraham says mezonot is no worse than wine -> RAE says wine doesn't work -> Only mezonot works not wine (!?))

Gil Student has an article entitled When Is A Kiddush Not A Kiddush? .
He quotes a teshuvah of Rav Moshe Feinstein (Iggeros Moshe, Orach Chaim 4:63). He writes that:

in this teshuvah there are two elements of kiddush.
One is that you must recite kiddush at your meal; the other is that
before you eat, you must recite kiddush. He does not consider the shul
kiddush a meal. However, since you recite kiddush before you eat, you
have not done anything wrong.
If I understand correctly, Rav Feinstein would not require you to eat
cake at a shul kiddush (although he would not object). According to
him, only bread/matzo creates a meal. So you are eating after kiddush
but not at a meal.  Do you have to repeat kiddush at lunch if you
already said it or heard it earlier? Rav Feinstein, requires it,
because you still have to say kiddush at a meal.

This teshuva allows a person to have kiddush without mezonos as long as he makes kiddush (again) before his meal.

"to have kiddush without mezonos as long as he makes kiddush (again) before his meal" I think you mean "to eat non-bread foods without kiddush as long as he makes kiddush before his bread meal"
